# How do you remove the last few characters from all lines in a txt file in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, evil, text-editing

How do you remove the last few characters from all lines in a text file?

Example:

```
23193 123252 1
1238 123 1
34356363 11238080123 1
```

Should become:

```
23193 123252
1238 123
34356363 11238080123
```

I'm using the evil interface in Spacemacs.

Comment: I ended up executing  :%s/.$// twice to remove the last two characters. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `..$` will match the last 2 characters in each line.